# How to grab an unknown pattern from a list in perl?

Tags: algorithm, perl

Is there a way to identify patterns in perl from a list? Lets say I have a file1:

```
123456
123abc456
123_abc_456
123_abc_d_456
abc_123_d_456
red123456blue
```

from this list I can clearly see that the pattern "123" and pattern "456" are common to all items in the list. So I want to store that as a variable.

Assume that the items in the list can only have characters (0-9)(a-z)(A-Z) and (_). Also assume that the pattern exists for every item in the list like in the example above. The pattern can be any length.

Comment: You're looking for the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff) describes and implements it for two strings. I don't have a reference for multiple strings.

Comment: What is the expected output for the example? Is it two patterns `123` and `345` or is it one pattern `123456`? For example if your list above also contained the item `12x3456`, do you just then delete the `x` and get `123456` or does the pattern `123` not longer exist as a solution and you only get the output `456`?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the hard way (brute-force) is quite forward:

```
use strict;
my @data=map {chomp; $_} (<DATA>);

my @candidates = (shift @data);
my %seen;
my @result;

OUT: while (@candidates) {
    my $current = shift @candidates;
    next unless $current;
    foreach my $found (@result) {
        next OUT
            if $found =~ /$current/;
    }
    foreach my $ele (@data) {
        unless ($ele =~ /$current/) {
            foreach my $n (substr($current,1), substr($current,0,-1)) {
                next if $seen{$n}++;
                push @candidates, $n;
            }
            next OUT;
        }
    }
    push @result, $current;
}

print Dumper (\@result);

__DATA__
123456
123abc456
123_abc_456
123_abc_d_456
abc_123_d_456
red123456blue
```

prints out:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '456',
      '123'
    ];
```

Removing the "inner loop"

```
foreach my $found (@result) {
    next OUT
        if $found =~ /$current/;
}
```

would find all matches:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '456',
      '123',
      '45',
      '23',
      '4',
      '3'
    ];
```